# Doxygen preprocessor modifiys/does not show correct defines inside a @code block on html page

Tags: c++, doxygen

Hello i have problem with the doxygen preprocessor. I have my documentation inside a .dox file. And i want to look at the dox in firefox, Doxygen is version 1.8.5 and cannot be changed
My `Doxfile.incl` looks like this

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
Project_Name = "XY"
FILE_PATTERNS += *.md
FILE_PATTERNS += *.dox
```

And my defines inside a code block looks like this:
`add_new_defines.dox`

```
@code

 /*Here are the defines you should add if you want to add this product*/
 #define ONE (LEVEL_ONE*5)
 #define TWO (LEVEL_TWO*5)
 #define THREE (LEVEL_THREE*5)
 +#define FOUR (LEVEL_FOUR*5)
 #else
 #define FIVE 500
 #define SIX 600

@endcode
```

This is how it should like and it, but when i execute `doxygen Doxfile.incl` and want to look at the documentation on firefox with `firfox index.html` the code looks like this:

```
/*Here are the defines you should add if you want to add this product*/
#define ONE 
#define TWO 
#define THREE 
    +#define FOUR (LEVEL_FOUR*5)
```

and with `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = NO` it looks like i wrote it in `add_new_defines.dox`

So my Question is there a Preprocessing command i can use to avoid this failure.
I tested `MACRO_EXPANSION  = YES` , `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` ,`MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES = 99`, `CPP_CLI_SUPPORT = YES`,`MARKDOWN_SUPPORT = NO`, `verbatim`. I guess it has to do somthing with the # in the beginning but how do i escape this without modifiying each defines here i have only 6 defines but in reality i have more then 100

Does work

```
#define ONE
+#define ONE (LEVEL_ONE*5)
*#define ONE (LEVEL_ONE*5)
```

this looks in html like this

```
#define ONE
+#define ONE (LEVEL_ONE*5)
#define ONE (LEVEL_ONE*5)
```

but with a space and # as first letter does not work

```
#define ONE (LEVEL_ONE*5)
```

Then it looks like this in the html

```
#define ONE
```

Comment: According to [doxygen's file extension table](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html#default_file_extension_mapping) a .dox file is interpreted as C++. I would guess doxygen parses everything in that file as (production) code, ignoring your `@code` markers. Wrap your entire file in `/** ... */` or set `EXTENSION_MAPPING=dox=md` or something like that.

Comment: Are you sure you are using doxygen 1.8.5? This is a version from August 23, 2013, the current doxygen version is 1.9.6. With the advise from @Friedrich the result looks OK (in the 1.8.5 version and based on the information provided i.e. the extra settings and the small code snippet) .

Comment: The documentation should only provide the defines that should be replaced if you want to add a specific product component into the programm so in the main programm there is a #if  and on the index page ther is a generated with doxygen 1.8.5 This is determined by the company.

Comment: So you want to use some logic inside the `dox` file? Did you have a look at `\if` comamnd and the `ENABLE_SECTIONS` setting. Push the company to update doxygen! or do you also use very old compilers and drive the decision makers around with horse and carriage?

Comment: If all else fails, write the documentation as HTML in a `code` tag and include that. No, I'm not proud of this idea.

Comment: if all else fails i can turn of the preprocessor this also works but i thought there is a way with preprocessor but maybe the version is to old

Comment: I still don't understand from your question whether you *do* want macro expansion or you *don't* want macro expansion or do you want macro expansion *in some places where you think it should be done*?

Comment: MACRO_EXPANSION  = YES was just some try, there is no source code or anything its just a documentation what you should do if  you want add something to the product, its just some text with instructions where to paste the code inside the @code blocks for diffrent products

Comment: And (as I said earlier) by putting this in a file with extension .dox you are telling doxygen "this file contains C++ code, please parse it as C++ code, please apply the macro extension on it". Use a different extension or tell doxygen it's not C++.

Comment: Okay but i dont need logic inside the dox

Comment: Is it even legal to have C-style comments inside a `@code` block? In a real C++ file, they would terminate the doxygen comment and break the build.

Comment: i guess it works the preprocessor does have a problem with `#` as first letter and a space in between, this does work `+#define ONE (LEVEL_ONE*5)` and this does not work  `#define ONE (LEVEL_ONE*5)` in html it looks like this `#define ONE`